# Jade.js with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, backbone.js, express, phonegap-plugins, pug

I have a node.js + express.js app that uses jade.js as the templating language. My app also uses Backbone.js as the client-side MVC.

I want to make this into a mobile app using PhoneGap. How do I package it? I don't have an index.html: it is all jade.

I have seen [GapServer](https://github.com/jgallen23/gapserver), but it is outdated and does not work.

Also, would I need to make all URLs in my app absolute instead of relative?

Is there a way to bundle all of this into a phonegap application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a bash build script to use the jade command for my .jade files. There are server-side solutions for compiling the jade, but I found this to be the easiest.

Example: jade login.jade -P -O ./phonegapBuild

I then zipped up the directory and I'm uploading it to Phonegap Build.

---

No jade can be rendered from the server using .render(""). The server needs to return JSON that the client then handles. The client can then change HTML pages using the locally bundled HTML files (Ex: window.location = "test.html").